# On-topicness of discussions about filtration/purification mechanics

Tags: discussion

We have a lot of questions/answers which revolve around the use of filters and purifiers for air and, even more, water.

**TL;DR**: It would be beneficial to TGO to have information that helps people with their bush-crafted filters. Would Q&As for various subtopics about absorbing chemicals, activated carbon, etc. be tolerated here? If not, suggestions for where else to put the various sub-topics would be appreciated.

Despite what some have claimed here on TGO, I have found that making your own filters, even reasonable quality carbon ones, completely sourced from foraged materials in an outdoor setting is a viable option for water treatment and possibly air treatment too. And not just for `survival` scenarios.

So I have no doubt that those question are a good fit here, but the problem I'm running into now is that these questions/answers then often beg a discussion of how to make the best filter. After all, most want their water as pure as possible, and it has to be a really good filter to work well for various air uses. This is a problem because this topic generally devolves into non-TGO knowledge that is used in TGO-style crafting.

In [my answer to the recent air filtration question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/20276/12799) I specifically skipped details about making charcoal and about activated carbon. TGO might be the best site for making charcoal (though it wouldn't surprise me if there's already a Q&A for that), but not so much for the rest of it. Because of this, we discussed in comments on the question until we could start a chat.

Ideally, we could link together related Q&As so they flow together nicely. But could questions about carbon filters *in general* be an ok fit on TGO? What about questions about activated charcoal?

If they are not wanted here, then where? Some of the discussion gets a little bit chemistry-related, and there is a chemistry SE I think. But that doesn't cover all of it. Maybe DIY SE could house some of it? Do you think some of the carbon surface-area/pore/absorbency stuff seems like an engineering SE thing? I'm willing to make Q&As wherever would be appropriate and to link to them from other SE sites, but I'm not sure where is a good fit... or even if you're just OK with having them here on TGO.

Comment: See also: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/on-topic-and-tag-suggestion-bush-crafting?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Would be great to have a clearinghouse for bushcraft water filters.  There’s a lot of opportunity to leverage technology from developing world.  I know there’s an MIT group testing water filters made from tree xylem (in brief—some tree branches provide exceptional filtration) 
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.technologyreview.com/s/520706/how-to-build-a-plant-xylem-water-filter/amp/

Note:  I’m a complete agnostic as to where on the various sites this should live

Comment: My initial knee-jerk reaction was to +1 this support for allowing the topic here. Not sure if I should have. As much as I _want_ it here for personal reasons, I feel like various sub-topics required would be migrated away to other sites unless we green-lit "Questions which would be off-topic will be virtually on-topic if they work well as foundational link-ins to what would be on-topic"... not sure that will fly.

Answer (score 2):

- Water filtration in the outdoors is on topic
- Water filtration/purification for a house gets migrated to diy.se
- A number of questions have already been asked on this subject, make sure yours are not dupes.

Comment: While I do enjoy the brevity of most of your questions and answers, and think it's a great thing 90% of the time, this is one of those cases where the details really are important as it is a nuanced question (though not at all hypothetical). You have technically answered the question as it appears in the title and possibly the TL;DR, though the answer is of very limited use. Perhaps I should not have included a TL;DR.

Comment: The previous is certainly not a slam. I'm not sure what I expected since TGO meta is not the "what SE does this go on?.SE" I suppose more of a discussion is what I was after. I'll ask around the metas of the other sites, starting with DIY at your suggestion, of what they think about these various related sub-topics.